# Using nth of child in CSS to create an uneven pattern?

Tags: css, css-selectors

There is a grid of 9 elements, their colors are like this:

```
Blue, Gray, Green
Green, Blue, Gray
Gray, Green, Blue
```

and then it repeats Blue, Gray, Green - how can I use nth of child to create this kind of pattern?

Comment: you can use 9n, 9n+1,…,9n+8 to style the elements. As an example: `.parentElementClass:nth-child[9n] { … }`, `.parentElementClass:nth-child[9n+1] { … }`

Comment: Thank you - is there any way to condense that so I don't have to write 9 different nth of children?

Comment: you can separate by comma the definitions with identical styles: `.classname:nth-child[9n], .classname:nth-child[9n+3] { … }`

Comment: I mean, is there any kind of formula that would get this kind of pattern within the first 3 elements? For example if it was Blue, Gray, Blue, Gray, Blue, Gray I could just do :nth-child(odd) and :nth-child(even) in 2 lines

Comment: maybe you find one, but i doubt it. do it this way

Comment: Can you share your `html` please?

Comment: @Gabriel Yes, you can simplify it a little more with css pre-processors such as SASS.

Comment: @Karan I didn't build it yet, but it will be similar as Loomy's code snippet down below except with actual content instead of just boxes - and the colors will represent the color of the font. I understand doing it this way with 9 separate nth of children, however it's bothering me that I can't think of an equation that can repeat this pattern with just the first 3 boxes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the rough and dirty way to accomplish this, using vanilla CSS and `:nth:child` formulas. With `:nth-child`, you are essentially writing a math expression to determine the behavior of elements that meet xn + y.  Since you know your starting size, it's fairly simple to declare each one:

```
.child:nth-child(9n+1){
    background: blue;
}
```

But you can view my snippet for a full demo.

```css
.parent{ 
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: max-content max-content max-content;
  gap: 10px;
}

.child{
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

.child:nth-child(9n+1){
  background: blue;
}
.child:nth-child(9n+2){
  background: gray;
}
.child:nth-child(9n+3){
  background: green;
}
.child:nth-child(9n+4){
  background: green;
}
.child:nth-child(9n+5){
  background: blue;
}
.child:nth-child(9n+6){
  background: gray;
}
.child:nth-child(9n+7){
  background: gray;
}
.child:nth-child(9n+8){
  background: green;
}
.child:nth-child(9n+9){
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

**Edit: Here is a less redundant version, using shared properties:**

```css
.parent{ 
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: max-content max-content max-content;
  gap: 10px;
}

.child{
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

.child:nth-child(9n+1), .child:nth-child(9n+5), .child:nth-child(9n+9){
  background: blue;
}
.child:nth-child(9n+3), .child:nth-child(9n+4), .child:nth-child(9n+8){
  background: green;
}
.child:nth-child(9n+2), .child:nth-child(9n+6), .child:nth-child(9n+7){
  background: gray;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: What would be a better way of doing something like this? Also is there any way to get the formula down in the first 3 lines, instead of spelling out the entire pattern in 9 separate nth-child selectors?

Comment: You could combine some of those selectors instead of having them separate.

Comment: As I mentioned in my other comment, another scriptless way to accomplish this would be to use a pre-processor, but eventually it will look similar to what I have above. If you want to slim it down a little, you can have multiple selectors all affected by the same properties. Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/vmh0ock7/